# IntelliJ IDEA: Use <name> instead of <artifactId> in project view?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

When importing a Maven project with subprojects, IDEA can recreate this structure in the Project view, which I use. But since my artifactIds are named by the purpose of the project, I have several artifacts named `model`, `impl`, `util` etc. which are then shown as `model (1)`, `model(2)` etc.

However, I added meaningful `<name>` tags in the POM. Is it possible to see the values of these tags instead of the artifactIds with added numbers (maybe even as a plug-in), or do I manually have to adjust the `.idea/modules.xml` to accomplish this?

Comment: I just wonder how it works that your modules have the same `artifactId`s- do your maven modules have different `groupId`s?

Comment: The groupIDs differ. We use the following approach: An artifact with `pom` packaging which is called like `com.foo.bar.awesomefeature`, with `groupId` of `com.foo.bar` and `artifactId` of `awesomefeature`, wherein there are artifacts with `groupId` of `com.foo.bar.awesomefeature` and `artifactIds` like `model`, `util`, `impl`. The `impl` is another `pom` packaged artifact with children with `groupId`s of `...awesomefeature.impl` and `artifactIds` describing the concrete thing. That way, adding a dependency, I can use the autocompletion. I just have to type `model` and select the thing.

Comment: I now changed `groupId`s and `artifactId`s so that the `groupId` of all projects is the same and the `artifactId` is extended. That way, I don't get `model (1)` and `model(2)` etc., but the `artifactIds`. Better, but still not the best solution using the `<name>`s

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think that you can configure IDEA to use `name` instead. Would be a nice feature though. Have you thought about contacting jetbrains for a feature request?