# IntelliJ Maven Module grouping

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have two Maven projects "SomeSuperName1" and "SomeSuperName2"

**Both** of these projects have an aggregator pom like this

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>com.company.yeah</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.company.yeah.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>SomeSuperName1</name>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>Child1</module>
        <module>Child2</module>
    </modules>
```

A module pom look like this

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.company.yeah.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>Child1</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
```

I want IntelliJ to show both projects in the project view using the Maven name "Some Super Name", i.e. like

```
- "SomeSuperName1"
- "SomeSuperName2"
```

but it constantly fails doing so. Instead the first project is added as "Some Super Name" while the other is put in a module group structure like

```
- "SomeSuperName1"
- parent (1) (com
   - company 
      - yeah
        - SomeSuperName2
```

I disabled "Create module groups for multi-module Maven projects" before importing both projects but no success.

Also importing via the "Maven Projects" View or via the File->New->Module from existing Sources doesn't help. Can anyone help pls? Problem is it's not only ugly imho but jumping to classes/methods doesn't work anymore. A workaround is to rename the module from "parent (1) (com.company.yeah.SomeSuperName2)" to just SomeSuperName2 but this change is gone when restarting IntelliJ.

Comment: Can you show us the module poms?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample project to reproduce attached.

Comment: This is essentially the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228938/intellij-idea-use-name-instead-of-artifactid-in-project-view - the two projects with artifactId "parent" are grouped under a "parent" node, despite having different groupId's.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with IntelliJ. Your pom file (or project structure) is misconfigured.

I think this will work.

```
<groupId>com.company.yeah.myapp</groupId>
<artifactId>SomeSuperName</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Here you can put any name</name>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<modules>
    <module>SomeSuperName1</module>
    <module>SomeSuperName2</module>
</modules>
```

[Here](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-simple-parent.html) you can find a nice reference.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh, I think I was not clear in my question. SomeSuperName1 and SomeSuperName2 are two completely separated projects. Both have a pom.xml like above, they do not have a common aggregator pom nor should they have one.

Comment: Ahh ok. But in that case i see both project have same parent. If they are not modules parent is obsolete (like mentioned in the answer ;)

Comment: And i guess u have one project per Intellij window (don't think it should matter). But Intellij is built/designed a bit differently and single frame (window) represents only one project.